# python: findall even if before found

Tags: python, regex

I have string like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

and code like this:

```
re.finditer(r'[ ]+([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3})[ ]+', s)
```

and there is as problem:
my return is 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, but i want 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

what can i do ?

Comment: Change the first `[ ]+` to `\b` *(a word boundary)* or `(?<=\s)` *(preceded by a whitespace)*. Since they are all the two zero-width assertion (they don't consume characters), the whitespace before that is already consumed by the previous match is only tested and don't need to be consumed an other time for the next match (that is impossible).

Comment: ok, its better now :) now it's return 1, 2, ..., 10 - but first and last haven't _space_ so i don't want it

Comment: update the page, I have edited my comment several times. The lookbehind `(?<=\s)` is more appropriated for what you want to do.

Comment: Note that you can also split your string and remove the first and last item in the result list.

Comment: this works:
`r'(?<=\s)([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3})[ ]+'`
there is one (or more) spaces at end and not stop after _first_ match - thx for help :)